# How swap slots in azure devops

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-functions, devops

I have two slots Prod and PreProd. How do I swap slots in azure devops release pipeline?
The first one is deploying to preprod after success then it is going to approval if approved then going to deploy to production. But I need to swap slots between preprod and prod.

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to define two steps:

- deploy to deployment slot
- and swap slot

[image]

To deploy to deployment slot you need to mark it and provide slot name:

[image]

And next in swap step define action which is `Swap Slots` and which slot is going to be swapped:

[image]

And please read this [blog entry](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/devops/considerations-on-using-deployment-slots-in-your-devops-pipeline/) if you are going to make swaps between preprod and prod environments. He disadvices this approach. And I fully agree with him.

Comment: Problem after swapping Slot configuration is changing. PreProd will use his setting and prod will use his settings. How will I swap without changing configuration?

Comment: @NoorAllSafaet I checked that and swapping doesn't change app settings. Are you sure? Can you give more details?

Comment: Settings will change if you don't set slotSettings to true. If the setting is checked with "slot setting" the settings STAY on that slot. Otherwise, it swaps with the other one.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the **Azure App Service Manage** Task.

[image: App Service Manage Task]

Comment: Will I use it instead of Azure App Service Deploy or before or after it? could you please give me a step?

Comment: @NoorAllSafaet you would usually use it AFTER you deploy. Deploy, then swap.

Answer (score 1):

1. Stage 1 -> With **Deploy Azure App Service** deploy to dev/pre-prod slot.
2. Clone State 1.
3. Add a post-deployment condition to Stage 1 for approval.
4. Remove **Deploy Azure App Service** task and add **Azure App Service Manage** task to Stage 2 to swap with production.